# Missing "version.h" when installing fglrx

Tags: fedora, drivers, hardware, graphics, fglrx

I have downloaded the fglrx driver installer from the ATI drivers page.

when I start the installation, everything goes smoothly until I hit an error message, telling me to check `/usr/share/ati/fglrx-install.log`.

The contents of that file are as follows:

> Check if system has the tools required
>   for installation. fglrx installation
>   requires that the system have kernel
>   headers. 
>   /lib/modules/3.8.11-200.fc18.x86_64/build/include/linux/version.h cannot be found on this system. One or
>   more tools required for installation
>   cannot be found on the system. Install
>   the required tools before installing
>   the fglrx driver. Optionally, run the
>   installer with --force option to
>   install without the tools. Forcing
>   install will disable AMD hardware
>   acceleration and may make your system
>   unstable. Not recommended.

Now, after a bit of searching around, I found that the symbolic link called `build` in `/lib/modules/3.8.11-200.fc18.x86_64` points to a nonexistent location.

I installed the `kernel-devel` package, and now it had pointed to an existing directory.

However, in the `/lib/modules/3.8.11-200.fc18.x86_64/build/include/linux/` directory, that is populated with various header files - I cannot find the one I need - `version.h`.

How can I solve this problem? Should I install the driver in a different manner? Which other package can I install to get the `version.h` file?

I'm running a clean install (default) of Fedora 18, which I had updated today.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Install the kernel-headers package and try again. If it doesn't work, try

`cp -v /usr/include/linux/version.h /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/build/include/linux`

Comment: I'm afraid that the file is still not there.

Comment: Edited my answer.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem installing newer AMD drivers on ubuntu/willy:

> fglrx installation requires that the system has kernel headers.
>   /lib/modules/4.2.0-42-generic/build/include/linux/version.h cannot be found on this system.
>   Install kernel headers using the command apt-get install linux-headers-4.2.0-42-generic.

Answers with cp and ln are good but first you have to do is find suitable version.h header on your system. For example using (on debian/ubuntu):

```
apt-file search version.h |  grep $(uname -r)
...
linux-headers-4.2.0-42-generic: /usr/src/linux-headers-4.2.0-42-generic/include/generated/uapi/linux/version.h
```

Only now you can be sure that you copy or link a good file to place where AMD wishes. In my case:

```
cp -v /usr/src/linux-headers-4.2.0-42-generic/include/generated/uapi/linux/version.h /lib/modules/4.2.0-42-generic/build/include/linux
```

Answer (score 0):

one can also link the header file:

```
ln -S /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/build/include/linux/version.h /usr/include/linux/version.h
```

Comment: Isn't your link syntax backwards?

Comment: @naught101 not exactly sure about the order of parameters right now; it's just an easy way to resolve absent headers - while the `ln` command has four forms of syntax: http://linux.die.net/man/1/ln

Comment: Ah, I mis-read that `-S` as `-s`. Confusing..

Comment: @syslogic: Really? The [suggested edit](http://unix.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/157035) looked right to me.

Comment: @G-Man read the above explanation (that was also S/s mistaken), while the path might vary in between distributions/versions (the one which I've used matches the one in the answer above). which should be nevertheless no problem, hence the `locate` command exists. please add your own answer.